# AngularJS ng-disabled passing more than one expression (using OR)

Tags: angularjs, select, expression

I need to block the input when selecting the options "Credit Card" or "Debit Card"

It works with just an expression, but when I do so using the OR it does not work

```js
app.controller('simuladorPedidoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $rootScope.listaPagto = [{ name: "A vista", id: 1 }, { name: "Boleto", id: 2 }, { name: "Cheque", id: 3 }, { name: "Cartão de Débito", id: 4 }, { name: "Cartão de Crédito", id: 5 }, { name: "Indefinido", id: 6 }];
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="simuladorPedidoCtrl">

  <label for="FormaPagamento" class="control-label">Forma de Pagamento</label>
  <select style="width: 100%" id="FormaPagamento" name="FormaPagamento" ng-model="model1.DadosPagamento.Forma"  class="form-control">
       <option value="">Selecione...</option>
       <option ng-repeat="item in $root.listaPagto | orderBy:'name'" value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</option>
  </select>

<label for="CartaoNome" ng-disabled="" class="control-label">Name</label>
<input type="text" ng-disabled="model1.DadosPagamento.Forma != 'Cartão de Crédito' || model1.DadosPagamento.Forma != 'Cartão de Débito'" class="form-control" id="CartaoNome" name="CartaoNome" ng-model="model1.DadosPagamento.CartaoNome">
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a logic problem. If it's a debit card, it's not going to be a credit card - If it's a credit card, it's not going to be a debit.

So, (notCredit || notDebit) will always return true.

I think it should be rearranged to the following logic:

```
ng-disabled="model1.DadosPagamento.Forma != 'Cartão de Crédito' && model1.DadosPagamento.Forma != 'Cartão de Débito'"
```

Comment: No, I want to block when I choose an option other than credit or debit card

For example when I choose "Billet" option the input need to be blocked.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.